# Another string to datevalue conversion for Excel

Tags: excel, date

This is another question on date string to datevalue conversion. 
Input format is "March 17, 2013 7:04:28 PM GMT-07:00".
(Output of SAP tool)

=DATEVALUE(B26) fails.

Any chances?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(B26,FIND(",",B26)+5))+TIMEVALUE(MID(B26,FIND(",",B26)+7,FIND("GMT",B26)-FIND(",",B26)-8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looking at two different things.  Datevalue is seperate from time.  For example, March 17, 2013 in Datevalue is equal to 41350.

```
=DATEVALUE(March 17, 2013)
```

Timevalue of 7:04:28 PM is equal to 0.794769

```
=TIMEVALUE(7:04:28 pm)
```

Both of these require the input to be in text format, not date or time.

You'll have to parse out the string and strip off the GMT at the end.  I don't think excel can evaluate time zones.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using US regional settings then your text is a valid date/time format once you remove "GMT" and everything after so you can use a formula that will simply remove that part and "co-erce" to a date/time value, i.e.

`=LEFT(B26,FIND("GMT",B26)-1)+0`

format result cell in the required date/time format, e.g. m/d/yy hh:mm